# Learning from JSON.Net Documentation Stalled. Can someone please provide MISSING GetPosts() Method?

Tags: c#, json.net

there are examples on both the https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDeclaratively.htm and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm web pages which call this method:

```
List<Post> posts = GetPosts();
```

Yes, tools like JSON do a wonderful job of organizing and querying volumes of textual information. But, as a beginner, one needs to master details very carefully.  It is way too easy to shoot oneself in the foot.  So, a missing example method-call is particularly painful.

Can anyone please reply here with a suitable C# implementation of GetPosts()?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, what GetPosts() does here is irrelevant.  The first page defined a Post object as:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

GetPost() just returns data from a database in the format above here.  The JSON code was showing how to map this Post object into the desired JSON format.  Thus, whether that method returns data from a database or is hard-coded, the code is the same when it refers to how to build up the JSON itself.

Just as an example, you could do this:

```
private List<Post> GetPosts()
{
   var posts = new List<Post>();
   posts.Add(new Post { Title = "X", Description = "Y", Link = "Z", Categories = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" });
   return posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you, Daniel, I was able to object-initialize List posts to compile.  Then, in turn, the Query and Debugger-examination worked too.   Once more, I’m a gentleman programmer.

Right in the middle of the 19-line from-in-select LINQ query is this innocent clause

```
from p in posts
```

From your reply, I now understand that the from-in query absolutely requires an object-initialized List or Array.  Without it, it won’t be a query.  It is just like “from t in tayble”, in T-SQL with tayble initialized by INSERT commands.  Two query pieces are inseparable: 1) an List/Array/table and 2) its initialization with INSERTs or with Object initialization.  No internet documentation told me that; without 2 pieces it won’t compile or work; but, you, Daniel did tell me that.

Remember those college professors who used to say “there are no bad questions”, but then they got hostile over questions about omitted details.  Same thing with Internet documentation; it reflects management’s hostility to documentation.  With spiffy color and formatting, such documentation appears to be very marketable.  Nonetheless it won’t work.  Pieces are missing.  It won’t compile.

Here's the working posts List’s object initialization.

```
        List<Post> posts = new List<Post>
{
new Post  { Title = "Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex",
             Description = "Announcing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and being available on CodePlex",
             Link = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx",
                          Categories = new List<string> { "Json.NET", "CodePlex" }
      },

new Post  {
        Title = "LINQ to JSON beta",
        Description = "Announcing LINQ to JSON",
        Link = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx",
        Categories = new List<string> { "Json.NET", "LINQ" }
        }
};
```